# Spotify API-NET Searchrequest no Type argument given

Tags: c#, spotify

I've been trying around a bit with the `spotifyAPI-NET`, and I just tried to create a SearchRequest which can search for an artist, but I can't seem to assign the arguments properly.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest {Type = SearchRequest.Types.Artist, Query = "Ren"};
```

[image: erroe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SearchRequest` constructor takes two required parameters i.e. `type` and `query`.

You're currently not passing any parameters to the constructor.

You need to change:

```
new SearchRequest {Type = SearchRequest.Types.Artist, Query = "Ren"}
```

to:

```
new SearchRequest(SearchRequest.Types.Artist, "Ren")
```

---

If you want to know more about how constructors work: [Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

---

[Search Request source code](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/0f6cdeb6930af43d4dfcd9f2184344368be22cd1/SpotifyAPI.Web/Models/Request/SearchRequest.cs)

```
public SearchRequest(Types type, string query)
{
    Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(type, nameof(type));
    Ensure.ArgumentNotNullOrEmptyString(query, nameof(query));

    Type = type;
    Query = query;
}
```

---

[Example from pagination.md](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/0f6cdeb6930af43d4dfcd9f2184344368be22cd1/SpotifyAPI.Docs/docs/pagination.md)

```
var search = await spotify.Search.Item(new SearchRequest(
    SearchRequest.Types.All, "Jake"
));
```

Comment: Alright thank you alot and have a good day ^^